# Copy all excel files from one location to another

Tags: vba, excel, copy

I have written the below script which creates a folder in a given location if it doesn't exist which is named after a cell in the workbook.

Dim fso As Object

```
Dim fldrname As String
Dim fldrpath As String
Dim sFileType As String
Dim sSourcePath As String
Dim Destination As String

Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
sSourcePath = "\\INSURANCE\IT\FileData\Computers\DIPS\"

fldrname = Worksheets("Applications").Range("A2").Value
fldrpath = "\\INSURANCE\IT\FileData\Computers\DIPS\DIP Archive\" & fldrname
If Not fso.folderexists(fldrpath) Then
fso.createfolder (fldrpath)
    End If
End If
```

I'm now trying to copy all .xlsm files in sSourcePath to the newly created location fldrpath & \ fldrname yet all attempts fail. I'm still fairly new to VBA so any help would be appreciated.
I have heard of .copyfile but i'm not sure how to utilise this in this example.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where are the attempts that failed? If you want to use the `.CopyFile` method you need to create a `FileSystemObject` and then call the method from it. It takes wildcards so it should do the job for you. It looks like you already have everything in place - except for reading the manual `object.CopyFile ( source, destination[, overwrite] )`

Comment: You only have one `If` statement, but you have two `End If` statements.  Is that a typo in this question, or is it actually like that in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My take on that

```
Sub copyFiles()

    Dim fldrname As String, fldrpath As String, sFileType As String
    Dim sSourcePath As String, Destination As String

    Dim fso As Object, fFolder As Object, fFile As Object

    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    sSourcePath = "\\SourcePath" '"\\INSURANCE\IT\FileData\Computers\DIPS\"

    fldrname = "data\" 'Worksheets("Applications").Range("A2").Value
    fldrpath = "\\SourcePath\Archive\" & fldrname '"\\INSURANCE\IT\FileData\Computers\DIPS\DIP Archive\" & fldrname

    If Not fso.folderexists(fldrpath) Then
        fso.createfolder (fldrpath)
    End If

    Set fFolder = fso.GetFolder(sSourcePath)

    For Each fFile In fFolder.Files

        'If Not (fso.FileExists(fldrpath & fFile.Name)) Then fFile.Copy fldrpath, Overwritefiles:=False
        fFile.Copy fldrpath, Overwritefiles:=True

    Next fFile

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

I do this without `filesystemobject`.

```
Sub copyfiles()
    Dim source_file As String, dest_file As String
    Dim source_path As String, dest_path As String
    Dim i As Long, file_array As Variant

    source_path = "\\INSURANCE\IT\FileData\Computers\DIPS"
    dest_path = "\\INSURANCE\IT\FileData\Computers\DIPS\DIP Archive"

    source_file = Dir(source_path & "\" & "*.xlsm")
    Do Until source_file = ""
        If Not IsArray(file_array) Then
            ReDim file_array(0) As Variant
        Else
            ReDim Preserve file_array(UBound(file_array) + 1) As Variant
        End If

        file_array(UBound(file_array)) = source_file
        source_file = Dir
    Loop

    'If new folder is not existed, create it.
    If Dir(dest_path, 16) = "" Then MkDir dest_path   '16=vbDirectory

    For i = LBound(file_array) To UBound(file_array)
        FileCopy source_path & "\" & file_array(i), dest_path & "\" & file_array(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```